# Отправление пакетов по UDP Python

Tags: python, сокет, клиент-сервер, udp

Моя программа отправляет строку по UDP и в ответ получает изображение. Но насколько я понимаю может произойти потеря пакетов или задержка, как можно сделать так чтобы каждое изображение полученное от сервера было помечено идентификационным номером, чтобы если будет задержка, изображение пришло в фоновом режиме и я знал к какому отправленному сообщению оно относится, чтобы не нужно было задерживать программу, потому что в этом случает при потере пакетов она зависнет и будет ждать ответа? Или может есть другие варианты как реализовать взаимодействие? Буду благодарен за совет.

Comment: Используй транспорт, например RTMP или QUIC

Comment: нум... нужно отправлять вместе с сообщением/изображением какой-либо идентификатор, чтобы было понятно, к чему оно относится... а чтобы не было «зависания» при потере надо использовать таймаут ожидания пакета (ваш кэп)

Comment: @Fat-Zer вместе с изображением это имеется ввиду два отдельных сообщения подряд или как-то вшить в сообщение с изображением его номер?

Comment: @АлександрТрифонов, просто поставить в начало пакета с изображением заголовок с нужной информацией... ЗЫ: ты об этом не спрашивал, но сразу хочу предупредить: объём дейтаграммы UDP ограничен в 64к, так что большИе изображения в одном пакете передать всё равно невозможно и придётся городить какой-то протокол поверх UDP, кроме того через большинство сетей размер нефрагментируемого IP-пакета всего ~1500 байт, так что для пакетов бОльшего размера вероятность потери возрастает кратно...